# While loop not displaying first result

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, loops, while-loop

I have the following code:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM Table WHERE YEAR = 2016";

$result = $db->query($query);
if($db->error)die($db->error);
$full = $result->fetch_assoc();

if(empty($full)) {
*do something*
}else{

while($match = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
*do something*
};
```

However my code is not displaying the first result in the `while` loop.

When I run the query through phpMyAdmin I get results starting with result 1, so I know my query is correct. However when I run it as part of this script it only displays results from the second result onwards.

How do I make the while loop display my first result?

Comment: `$full = $result->fetch_assoc();` Here is your first result fleeing, catch it!

Comment: Thanks Rizier! However, taking out that line causes my if statement after it to fail. Any thoughts how I can do both?

Comment: Not to worry, I fixed it with `if(empty($result->fetch_assoc))`. Thanks again!

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php

Comment: Yep that way works better. Thanks again Rizier.